# IplImage in ( com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage) to Mat in org.opencv.core.Mat

Tags: android, javacv

i'm using javacv in android , but in android the frame in Mat ,how can i convert it to   IplImage
i tried conversion like what i did in c++
    Mat image1
    hereIplImage* image2=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)image1)

it didn't work , help plz:(

as i want to reuse http://codersadda.com/javacv-color-based-thresholding-in-image-using-opencv/menu-id-40 this in my android App

Comment: `IplImage` is deprecated and shouldn't be used (it might not even be available in newer versions of OpenCV). Use the `Mat` class instead.

Comment: @Michael you mean i can't use http://codersadda.com/javacv-color-based-thresholding-in-image-using-opencv/menu-id-40 in android app??

Comment: Mat m(iplimage); // there's a constructor for that

Answer (score 0):

You only create an `IplImage` type `img` for example, and given that `matImage` is you `cv::Mat` object, use this:

```
IplImage img = output.operator IplImage();
```